# JPA: One to One relationship with Entity of exact type

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Suppose you have the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER (
    USER_NAME               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    SECOND_NAME             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SURNAME                 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    BIRTH_DATE              DATE NOT NULL,
    BIRTH_GENDER            ENUM ('M', 'F') NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CREATED_BY              VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY         VARCHAR(20),
    DELETION_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP NULL,
    DELETED_BY              VARCHAR(20),

    PRIMARY KEY (USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (CREATED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (LAST_UPDATED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (DELETED_BY) REFERENCES USER(USER_NAME)
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I have the following JPA entity as follows:

```
/**
 * @author Buhake Sindi
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1600376007707987934L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="SECOND_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String secondName;

    @Column(name="SURNAME", nullable=false)
    private String surname;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="BIRTH_DATE", nullable=false)
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name="BIRTH_GENDER", columnDefinition="ENUM('M', 'F')", nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender birthGender;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="CREATION_TIMESTAMP", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private Date creationTimestamp;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CREATED_BY", insertable=true, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private User createdBy;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see za.co.sindi.entity.IDBasedEntity#getId()
     */
    public String getId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see za.co.sindi.entity.IDBasedEntity#setId(java.io.Serializable)
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the secondName
     */
    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    /**
     * @param secondName the secondName to set
     */
    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the surname
     */
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param surname the surname to set
     */
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the birthDate
     */
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthDate the birthDate to set
     */
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the birthGender
     */
    public Gender getBirthGender() {
        return birthGender;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthGender the birthGender to set
     */
    public void setBirthGender(Gender birthGender) {
        this.birthGender = birthGender;
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see za.co.sindi.entity.AbstractIdentifiableAuditableEntity#getCreationTimestamp()
 */
    @Override
    public Date getCreationTimestamp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return creationTimestamp;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see za.co.sindi.entity.AbstractIdentifiableAuditableEntity#setCreationTimestamp(java.util.Date)
 */
@Override
public void setCreationTimestamp(Date creationTimestamp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see za.co.sindi.entity.AbstractIdentifiableAuditableEntity#getCreatedBy()
 */
@Override
public User getCreatedBy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return createdBy;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see za.co.sindi.entity.AbstractIdentifiableAuditableEntity#setCreatedBy(java.lang.Object)
 */
    @Override
    public void setCreatedBy(User createdBy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
}
```

The problem is when mapping attribute `createdBy` to `CREATED_BY` column. When deploying it to RedHat Wildfly 8.2.0 Final, it runs into an infinite loop (StackOverflow error). How do I map it correctly so that the relationship may have an One-On-One without JPA going crazy?

---

I don't know why this is relevant but my `persistence.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myapp-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider><!-- used since Hibernate 4.3.x instead of org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence -->
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/MyAppXADS</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode><!-- This is the default anyway. -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" /><!-- DBA's are paid to create DB tables so never do update | create | create-drop. -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

Comment: can you please add your persistence.xml

Comment: I'm using JPA 2.1 Persistence framework, why do you need my `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I used your sql and entity definitions and it works fine, I want to see the configuration, just to simulate in my environment

Comment: I did not find any problem, I voted up, I hope  another developer can help

Comment: First, I doubt a user is only allowed to create one other user. So it's not a OneToOne, but a ManyToOne. Second, if you get an exception, post its stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem to this issue was that the `User` entity was a subclass of a `@MappedSuperclass` `AbstractSoftDeleteAuditableEntity` (which was generic-fied). In the `MappedSuperclass` entity, the `createdBy`, `lastUpdatedBy` and `deletedBy` attribute were assigned to the bounded type `User`. When deploying the application, Hibernate went on a cyclical loop trying to validate the `User` entity and resulted in a `StackOverflowError`. I made `User` entity a simple entity and now all entities are deployed and validated with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

The mappings look good, so I assume it must be the actual database state causing the issue.

You declared `CREATED_BY` to be `NOT NULL`; so how do you insert the first user in an empty `USER` table? The only way to solve it is to indicate that the first user actually created herself.

And if that is the case (or you have self-referencing users for any other reason, for example if this is the way you save users who registered themselves and are created by no other user), then there is a lot of potential for an infinite recursion. For example, check your `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` (I don't see them in `User` class you posted, maybe you omitted them for brevity).

I would expect Hibernate to handle this situation, but maybe it tries to resolve `createdBy` association repeatedly in the same `User` instance.

Whatever the reason, the stack trace of the error should give a hint of where the infinite recursion originates from.

Also, you may want to enable `TRACE` log level for `org.hibernate` package to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: `The only way to solve it is to indicate that the first user actually created herself.`. BINGO! That's the only way you can create oneself. I will post the actual problem that occurred and how I fixed it.